# Can I Serve Map Layers Directly from Vertica?

Tags: geoserver, vertica

In Geoserver, it's possible to use a PostGIS database as a Vector Data source.

Is there an easy way to connect to a Vertica database instead in the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not at present. It would be possible to write a new [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) datastore that would read (and write) to a Vertica database. [This tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/datastore/index.html) takes you through the process. Once you have a new datastore it is simply a question of dropping the new jars into the GeoServer lib directory and restarting, you can also provide a [custom datastore page](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/programming-guide/web-ui/index.html) for GeoServer.